# Beauty name instead id

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm

I have a two table:

```
Users:
id,
name,
role_id

Roles:
id,
name
```

And i will response to requset like this:
user_id, user_name, role_name (not the role_id)

My controller for route function:

```
public function getUserList(): JsonResponse {
     $users = User::All()->toArray();

     return response()->json($users);
}
```

How include roles.name field in the response ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function getUserList(): JsonResponse {
  return response()->json(User::with('role')->get());
}
```

*Note: You don't need to call `->toArray()` when returning as a JSON response; that is done automatically*

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Then `user.role.name` on your front-end.

If you want `user.role_name` instead of `user.role.name`, then you'll need to define an accessor and append it:

`User.php`:

```
class User extends Model {
  public $appends = ['role_name'];

  public function role() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
  }

  public function getRoleNameAttribute() { 
    return $this->role->name;
  }
}
```

Now, `user.role_name` will be available.

Answer (score 2):

Create a relationship on your User model.

```
class User extends Authenticable
{
    public function role()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
    }
}
```

Include the relationship using `with()`.

```
$users = User::with('role')->get();
```

This will transform it into the following structure, when the models are transformed to `JSON`.

```
[
    {
        "name": "Martin",
        "email": "me@email.com",
        "role": {
            "name": "admin"
        }
    }
]
```

Working with `Laravel`, i will call it an anti pattern, transforming objects or data structures to arrays. In between classes, keep em objects for flexibility. In controllers `Laravel`, is smart enough to automatically transform your data. So the following code, is enough for a `JSON` route.

```
public function getUserList()
{
    return User::with('role')->get();
}
```

Comment: Few notices: for consistency it's good to have it as `with(['role'])` (attention on array as argument). And for having particular column(s) from relationship, it can be done as `with(['role:name'])`. [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-specific-columns).